# Make different image Objects in processing.js

Tags: javascript, arraylist, processing.js

I ama trying to display some images in the browser and when you click on the image you get the image which you are pressed in the mouse position but when i press the first element in the array nothing happened but when i press second element it is showing but when i press first again the second one is showing again. I asume that there is some issue with the value of the array it is just changeing only once and not anymore.
Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList();

String pic ;
PImage images [];
PImage image;
int x;
int y;
int pad = 10;
int bs = 70;
String val ="index.jpg images.jpg";
String[] list;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  change(val);
}

void draw() {
background(150);
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    x = pad + (bs+pad)*i;
    y = pad;
    image(images[i], x, y, bs, bs);
    over();
  }
  for (Object o : objects) {
    o.show();
  }
}

void over() {
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width/x+bs*i && 
      mouseY > y && mouseY <= pad+bs) {
      fill(255);
      println(images[i]);
      image = images[i];
      rect(x, y, bs, bs);
    }
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width/x+bs*i && 
      mouseY > y && mouseY <= pad+bs) {
      float xpos = mouseX;
      float ypos = mouseY;
      objects.add(new Object(xpos, ypos, image));
    }
  }
}

void mouseDragged() {
  for (Object o : objects) {
    o.moove();
  }
}


/* ---------------------------------------------*/

void change(String val) {
  list = split(val, " ");
  images = new PImage[list.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {    
    images[i] = loadImage(list[i]);
  }
}
```

And the object is here:

```
class Object{
float x;
float y;
PImage img;
int block = 50;

  Object(float tmpx, float tmpy, PImage tmpimg){
    x = tmpx;
    y = tmpy;
    img = tmpimg;
  }

void show (){
  image(img,x,y,block,block);
}

  void moove() {
      x = mouseX - block/2;
      y = mouseY - block/2;
  }

}
```

Comment: In the `over()` method, maybe change `if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width/x+bs*i && mouseY > y && mouseY <= pad+bs) {` to `if (mouseX >= x && mouseX < x+bs && mouseY >= y && mouseY < y + bs) {`.  If I am correct in assuming that the image size should be 70x70, based on `bs`, then this should do what you want.  But I have not actually tried the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to debug your code.

I would start by drawing circles at points of interest. For example, drawing a circle at `x,y` shows us that `x,y` points to the upper-left corner of the **second** image. Are you sure that's what you want?

It probably isn't, because you want to be able to check both images separately. To fix that, I would honestly just get rid of `x` and `y` as global variables, and just do the calculations in each of your `for` loops for each image.

Also, note that it's pretty bad practice to have a class named `Object`. This might not break anything (especially if you're using JavaScript mode), but at best it's going to be confusing. It's better to use more descriptive class names, like `ImageAtPoint` or something.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestions i will take your advices, I name my test examples with simple names just to make things working and after that when i implement my code i'll try to name things propperly. But i found my mistake the part of the code where i create the object itself `(mousePressed(){} function)` i check the position of the mouse and that brake my code for some reason i delete that code and everything works now. Once again thank you for the adices and the help.